# Changing row data to column data vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple question. I need to transform data from example A1 to lastcolumn in sheet1 to from a1 to lastrow in existing sheet2 (by VBA). Can anyone help me with that? I've been working on huge VBA code (for me) and I cannot proceed with that simple thing. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZEjC.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBpky.png

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("C1:ADI1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("raportPDF").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.UnMerge
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: show your code attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can use the [`transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) method in Excel VBA.

If you want to do it manually inside Excel, you can do the following:

- Select and copy the original data.
- Select the first cell of the destination range.
- Right click the destination cell and choose **Paste Special** in which you can choose **Transpose**.